# mod_rewrite interferes with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an issue involving PHP and mod_rewrite.

I am trying to load the page `example.com/1`.

### index.php

```
<?php

// get requested uri
$uri = explode('/', strtolower(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1)));

var_dump($uri[0]);

// route current page
if ($uri[0] == '1'){
    $page_id = '<br />1';
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}

echo $page_id;

?>
```

The var_dump gives out `string(1) "1"` and the page_id echoed is `1`.

The problem is that I also get the following warning.

> PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at PATH:6) in /PATH on line 12

Line 6 is the var_dump.

Line 12 is the header line.

I should not be getting that warning since that code should not be getting run.

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]

IndexIgnore *
Options -Indexes
```

### example.com virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName example.com

DocumentRoot PATH/example.com/public

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/example.com-error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.com-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**Some things I've tried.**

When I remove the `.htaccess` file and replace `1` by `index.php` and try to access `example.com/index.php` I don't get the error.

If I set the `$uri[0] = '1';` manually I don't get the warning.

If I set the `$uri = '/1';` manually I don't get the warning.

If I add more code to the `else {`, like set the `$page_id` to something else, it doesn't do anything. It seems like only header lines get executed and produce a warning.

It seems like the mod_rewrite is somehow messing up the `$_SERVER` variable. Maybe some kind of encoding issue since the var_dump is normal.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a PHP error more than anything else.

If there is ANY output from a script, you can NOT do a header() function anymore. So

`echo 1; header(...)`

Will fail, because you sent the number 1 back to the client already. So your var_dump sends some output, and this causes the header() function to fail. Remove the var_dump.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The header should not be executed because it's in the else statement.